# State_machine gem transition failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, state-machine

I am at the end of the Hartl tutorial and am using the state_machine gem to setup an signup email confirmation process (I know it's a bit code heavy for this simple use case but I'm doing it to learn).

I have inserted the following code into my user model:

```
state_machine initial: :inactive do
    event :confirm do
      transition :inactive => :active 
    end
  end
```

and when I go into the rails console, find a user and try transition from inactive to active it fails:

```
2.0.0-p481 :040 > u = User.find(1)
  User Load (2.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
 => #<User id: 1, name: "Example User", email: "example@railstutorial.org", created_at: "2014-09-09 08:28:20", updated_at: "2014-09-09 08:28:20", password_digest: "$2a$10$.Fhol/ebeFxVKT1HTvDTce/c.zC5D0MLMH.fTqPzMnNf...", remember_token: "bdfa52f05e2f8357ff95e6354af0565a6dca9a83", admin: true, state: "inactive"> 
2.0.0-p481 :041 > u.state
 => "inactive" 
2.0.0-p481 :042 > u.state_events
 => [:confirm] 
2.0.0-p481 :043 > u.confirm
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (4.8ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('example@railstutorial.org') AND "users"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
   (0.9ms)  ROLLBACK
 => false
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong? I suspect it has to do with this snippet:

```
"users"."id" != 1
```

but I have no idea why the sql query is doing that?

Comment: What happens if you use `u.confirm!`? (notice the `!`)

Comment: `2.0.0-p481 :063 > u.confirm!   

   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (1.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('example@railstutorial.org') AND "users"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK   

StateMachine::InvalidTransition: Cannot transition state via :confirm from :inactive (Reason(s): Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters))`   

I commented out the password validation in the user model and reloaded the user into memory in the console but it still gives this error.

Comment: So there you go, there's a validation somewhere that's preventing the record to change. Update the password to use one with a correct length (more than 6 characters), and then you will be able to transition the state :)

Comment: It is strange that the password and password_confirmation fields were empty. I have a rake task setup to generate 100 users with all details filled in. Your fix worked though. Thanks a million.